# Horizontally centering a child element inside a parent narrower than the child element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to horizontally center a wide `<img>` element inside a `<div>` which is not as wide as the image itself. And the `<div>` has `overflow: hidden` set on it.

For instance, the image is `500px` wide and the DIV is `250px` wide. Is there any clean way (such that it works for images of any dimension) to center the image such that only the center portion shows up inside the div.

Comment: what is the purpose for this? Why not just crop the image down? Unless you are planning to scroll in different directions? You can always use position: x, y; for your image as well.

Comment: You may  need to have multiple dimensions of images.

Comment: @Keith - The image(s) in question cannot be altered as I need the same image in different views. Secondly, the reason i can't simply have it as a background positioned correctly is I want it parsed by search engines as a proper image element with a SE relevant `title` and `alt`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="Container">
    <img class="Thumb">
</div>
```

And :

```
.Container {
    position: /* anything but static */
    width: 250px;
}

.Thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I cannot have the inner image skewed. It needs to be shown in its original size/proportion, just that only a part of it (the center part) is to be visible.

Comment: You can also use the image as the background of your outer div and use background-position: center;

Comment: The reason i can't simply have it as a background positioned correctly is I want it parsed by search engines as a proper image element with a SE relevant `title` and `alt`.

Comment: Why would the image be skewed anyway ? Just specify it's size and it will be centered as long as you keep the margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

you can add your image as a background using css and give background position to center center.

Comment: The reason i can't simply have it as a background positioned correctly is I want it parsed by search engines as a proper image element with a SE relevant `title` and `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're expecting a responsive behavior, I would suggest to have (for a simple one)

```
div {
 text-align: center;
}
```

But using ***CSS3 and media queries*** it is possible.

Check this out [**How to Create a Responsive Centered Image in CSS3**](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-responsive-centered-image/)

Quick [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/responsive-image)

Comment: The demo involves resizing the image according the container which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, `text-align: center;` for the container does not work when the child is wider than the parent!